# cordova -Error vs-tac when I try compile iOS remote

Tags: ios, node.js, visual-studio, cordova

I have a solution on Cordova 6.3 on Visual Studio 2017, my remote agent is a local MacBook Pro. I can connect to remote agent, because i see the conection Ok, but, I can't compile because I has seeing an error.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enviando la compilación al servidor de compilación remoto
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
------ Compilación incremental: False
------ Enviando nueva solicitud de compilación a: https://MACBOOKPRO-4526:3000/cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=6.3.1&cfg=debug
1>  MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Se produjo un error al cargar al servidor de compilación https://MACBOOKPRO-4526:3000/cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=6.3.1&cfg=debug: Se excedió el tiempo de espera de la operación
------ 07/21/2017 18:26:51 Comprobando el estado de la compilación desde  [Intento 1]
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018: Error inesperado en la tarea "VsTac".
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018: System.ArgumentNullException: El valor no puede ser nulo.
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018: Nombre del parámetro: requestUriString
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    en System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String requestUriString)
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    en Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RemoteBuild.CreateWebRequest(String url)
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    en Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RemoteBuild.PollForBuildComplete(String buildingUrl, Int32 interval, Int32 attempts)
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    en Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RemoteBuild.Build()
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    en Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.VsTac.BuildPlatform()
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    en Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.VsTac.Execute()
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    en Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    en Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
1>Compilación terminada del destino "BuildMDA" en el proyecto "ResarApp2016 v2.jsproj" -- ERROR.
```

I has tried reinstall `npm remotebuild` and `npm cordova`, reinstall `xcode` too, but i can't compile.

Can you help me?

Regards from Mexico,